# How can I detect if PIX is running?

Tags: direct3d

My application adapts to a slow framerate in a few different ways.  When I run a PIX experiment, rendering gets much slower so these techniques get activated.  I would like to disable this without having to do a seperate build when I want to use PIX.  Something like:

```
if (running_slow() && !running_pix()) {
    reduce_graphics();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DirectX June 2010 SDK:

```
bool running_pix() {
    return D3DPERF_GetStatus() != 0;
}
```